# OS X - sending file from computer to microcontroler

Tags: macos, file, bluetooth, transfer

I need to send binary file from Mac os X app to another device(which is waiting for this file transmission).
I know how to open bluetooth session between this two devices (one is Macbook, another - microcontroller) and start sending/receiving single chars/strings - but I cant find an example how to send whole file(up to 32kb size).
Can anybody help me please?

Regards

Przemek

Comment: By converting your file into `NSData`, and the Bluetooth device has to know that's a file ?

Comment: Yes, device which is recipient of this file wait for .bin file. I tried to find some examples how to convert this file into NSData - can you point me to good tutorial? Thank you so much!

Comment: Look at NSData methods in the doc. There are something like initWithFile: